# Has G.K. Chesterton written any fantasy novels beside "The Man Who Was Thursday"?

Tags: urban-fantasy, g-k-chesterton, the-man-who-was-thursday

As it says on the tin. I remember reading *The Man Who Was Thursday* almost a decade ago and was wondering if his other novels are fantasy or something else.

Comment: Wikipedia has a quite extensive [list of his works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._K._Chesterton_bibliography), but as I haven't read any of them I'll leave it to those who have to point out which are fantasy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even *The Man Who Was Thursday* is a bit borderline as a fantasy novel. While set in a political situation that never existed, there is nothing inherently 'fantastic' about it. Both *The Napoleon of Notting Hill* and *The Flying Inn* are set in 'alternate' presents, and so would count as 'fantasy' to at least the same extent as *The Man Who Was Thursday*. But most of his works are not.

Comment: The Napoleon of Notting Hill was set in 1984 (80 years in the future, relative to when it was published), so although that's now in the past, I wouldn't call it an alternate present. It just happens to be a future London that hasn't changed much in terms of fashion and technology (at least at the start).